# Чек-марк не работает

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Есть одна таблица, там где размещаются данные человека и чек-марк. Данные выводятся и сам чек-марк, только стоит он на автомате включен. Когда я нажимаю выключить - он не нажимается и не выключает чек-марк. Вот мой код

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    if let myName = user.name {
        cell.textLabel?.text = myName
    }
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    return cell
}
```

Comment: И как он должен выключаться? Вы просто показываете его в ячейке. Должна быть логика, задающая поведение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавте масив как свойство контроллера

```
var selectedIndex:[Int] = [] //тут будем хранить индексы выбранных строк
//private var selectedIndex:[Int] = [] //или так, если нам не нужен доступ вне контроллера
```

Измените метод

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = UITableViewCell()
     let user = users[indexPath.row]
     if let myName = user.name {
         cell.textLabel?.text = myName
     }
     if self.selectedIndex.contains(indexPath.row){ //проверяем есть ли такой елемент в нашем массиве
         cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
     } else {
         cell.accessoryType = .none
     }
     return cell
}
```

Добавте или измените метод

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // тут проверяем если ячейка уже выбрана то удаляем из массива и убираем чекмарк
    // если не выбрана то добавляем в массив и ставим чекмарк
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        self.selectedIndex.remove(at: self.selectedIndex.index(of: indexPath.row)!)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        self.selectedIndex.append(indexPath.row)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false) //убираем выделение ячейки если не нужно обратное
}
```